# Revocation information not available for certificate?

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to download SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition from MSDNAA on my Windows 7 laptop. When I attempted to start the download, I was shown the following prompt:

> Revocation Information for the security certificate for this site is not available. Do you want to proceed?
>   [Yes] [No] [View Details]

The details for the certificate say that it was issued to extended-validation-ssl.verisign.com by VeriSign.

I opted to click no. The downloader application wouldn't download the file, since I'd refused to accept the certificate.

I restarted the downloader application, and evidently it picked a different server, since the download is now working and I haven't seen the prompt.

I would like to know why there was no revocation information for the certificate. Should I be worried about this?

Considering the recent issues some certificate authorities have had, I don't wish to accept certificates if my laptop cannot determine whether or not they have been revoked.